Proof of K-theory version of Poincaré duality for closed spin$^c$ manifold
Let $X$ be a oriented Riemannian $n$-manifold. It seems to be well known that if $X$ is closed and spin$^c$ then the Poincaré duality reads
$$ K^*(X) \cong K_{*+n}(X)$$
between the complex K-theory and K-homology groups.
To prove it the idea is to construct two elements $\Delta \in KK^n(C(X) \otimes C(X),\mathbb{C})$ and $\Delta^\vee \in KK^{-n}(\mathbb{C},C(X) \otimes C(X))$ such that
$$ \Delta^\vee \otimes_{C(X)} \Delta = 1 \in KK^0(C(X), C(X)) $$
where $\otimes_{C(X)}$ is the Kasparov product.
I see in some paper/book [1,Theorem 10.2.15] that these class are construct as :

Construction of $\Delta$ : The Dirac operator determines a class $[D] \in KK^n(C(X),\mathbb{C})$. Consider the diagonal map $\delta : X \rightarrow X \times X$. It extends to a map $\delta^* : KK^n(C(X),\mathbb{C}) \rightarrow KK^n(C(X) \otimes C(X),\mathbb{C})$. Then, we let
$$ \Delta := \delta^*([D]) \in KK^n(C(X) \otimes C(X),\mathbb{C})$$
Construction of $\Delta^\vee$ : Consider $\nu \rightarrow X$ the normal bundle to the embedding $\delta : X \rightarrow X \times X$. This bundle determine a Thom class $\xi_\nu \in KK^{-n}(\mathbb{C},C(\nu))$. Consider $\varphi: \nu \rightarrow X \times X $ the tubular neighbourhood embedding and we know this map induced a group homomorphism $\varphi ! : KK^{-n}(\mathbb{C},C(\nu)) \rightarrow KK^{-n}(C(X) \otimes C(X),\mathbb{C})$. Then, we let

$$\Delta^\vee := \varphi!(\xi_\nu) \in KK^{-n}(\mathbb{C},C(X) \otimes C(X))$$
Problem : I cannot show that $\Delta^\vee \otimes_{C(X)} \Delta = 1$. My problem it's that i'm not even able to find a explicit Kasparov module which represent $\varphi!(\xi_\nu) = (E,\phi,F)$ and who could help me to operate the Kasparov product ... Has anyone already done the calculation? Is there another method to compute this product?
[1] H.Emerson, An Introduction to C*-algebras and Noncommutative
Geometry
